# DRF: how can I catch the internal error (500 http response) and do some routine?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an APIView and I have overrode [`finalize_response`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#finalize_responseself-request-response-42args-kwargs) method to log some information. It works fine but the problem is that, `finalize_response` won't be called when an internal error happens! While server responses with 500 status and some message! How can I catch internal error and log information about response?

```py
class MyApiView(APIView):

    ...

    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        # doing some logging stuff!
```

Comment: Why don't you put that logic inside a middleware instead of overriding `finalize_response` ?

Comment: @Bulsky like how? I'm new in DRF! and overriding `finalize_response` was easy! so...

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/ You can then trigger action before and after calling the view (using `process_view`), and eventually trigger other actions in case of exception (using `process_exception`).

Comment: @Blusky as far as I understand, it will be applied to all of the views! which is not what I want. What I want is that do those routine processes in some specific views, namely `MyApiView`.

Comment: You can retrieve the view from the middleware and do "nothing" if the request is not from the related view.